# D3js - Multiple Instances of Single External SVG File

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This is somewhat of an **abstract question**. I'm referencing **Mike Bostock's** code for importing an external `svg` file: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1014829

My plan is to use an external `SVG` as an `icon` (or `sprite`) that will be used multiple times in one interface.  Is there a method for creating a copy of the `xml.documentElement` below? In summary, how does one create multiple instances of one `svg` file without loading the file for each instance?

```
d3.xml("rect01.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
});
```

The end goal is to add an external `svg` to each cell in the grid created from this example: http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2605010

Referencing the link above, how does one work the `xml.documentElement` data into the grid in the code below, so that the external `svg` is visible, rather than a rectangle?

```
   var col = row.selectAll(".cell")
                 .data(function (d) { return d; })
                .enter().append("svg:rect")
                 .attr("class", "cell")
                 .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
                 .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
                 .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
                 .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height; })
                 .on('mouseover', function() {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .style('fill', '#0F0');
                 })
                 .on('mouseout', function() {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .style('fill', '#FFF');
                 })
                 .on('click', function() {
                    console.log(d3.select(this));
                 })
                 .style("fill", '#FFF')
                 .style("stroke", '#555');
}
```

Comment: include them via an `<object>` or `<iframe>` tag perhaps? Or use a `<use>` tag to visualise SVG markup in more than one place.

Comment: I think I found a good lead here: http://jsfiddle.net/christopheviau/XnG6r/

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/christoph), the line of code I needed is `cloneNode(true)`:

```
.each(function(d, i){ 
        var plane = this.appendChild(importedNode.cloneNode(true)); 
        d3.select(plane).select("path").attr("fill", "blue");
    })
```